# What Is The Git Link On A Remote Repository

Tags: git, command-line, ssh, git-remote

I am new to `git`. I have been working on making git push to my remote repository. I have a website with cPanel. I have `ssh` access and I used the commands from [the cPanel Forums](http://forums.cpanel.net/f391/installing-git-294411.html).

I used this sequence of steps to install `git` to my remote server which installed perfectly with the latest `git` version:

```
cd ~
wget http://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.7.9.2.tar.gz
tar zxvf git-1.7.9.2.tar.gz
cd git-1.7.9.2
./configure --prefix=/home/$USER
make
make install
echo 'PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin' >> $HOME/.bashrc
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

The only question I have now is, what is the link that I put into the `git` command line or `tortoisegit` when I want to clone, push, and pull?

Example from github: `git@github.com:username/try_git.git`

Example to what I thought would work in my case: `name@website.com:directory/gitrepo.git`

To be more specific, what does the following lines of code do:

```
echo 'PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin' >> $HOME/.bashrc
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

I installed git on my domain server, which I don't have root access too, that is why I used the installation process from the link above. However, when I try to push or clone from what I thought was the file path it keeps giving me errors the following error(s):

```
Using username "git-upload-pack 'nathan".
Access denied
Access denied
Access denied
Access denied

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (36910 ms @ 12/31/2012 8:03:02 AM)
```

Could this be caused by using tortoiseGit?

Other question I might ask is what is a command line example of cloning, push, or pulling from my remote server that only has git installed?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following link pattern in your code:

```
https://username@github.com/directory/projectname.git
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I tried what you said and it gave me this error: error: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol while accessing https://username@website.com/gittest/repo.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed

Comment: Am I suppose to use something like ssh://username@website.com:linkto/projectname.git ?